# What is best practice for retrieving a single object from database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

So I have my database on MongoDB and it is stored in state via Redux, for when I want to view a single item or load a single item for updating what is the best practice for retrieving it?

currently I have it set up with hash location in the URL and adding item ID in the URL and then retrieving the ID and checking to make sure it is found before loading data/error

```
const recipeId = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  const recipe = useSelector((state) =>
    state.recipes.find((r) => r._id === recipeId)
  );
```

my reducer

```
const reducer = (recipes = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_ALL_RECIPES":
      return action.payload;
    case "CREATE_RECIPE":
      return [...recipes, action.payload];
    default:
      return recipes;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are selecting "recipes" from Redux Store into your component? The answer depends on how you are doing that.